# How to flag a message & query flagged messages using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to "flag" messages using Microsoft Graph?

I have tried the following but to no avail as it throws an error.

```
client.Me.Messages[messageId]
    .SingleValueExtendedProperties
    .Request ()
    .AddAsync (new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {
            Id = "Integer 0x1090", Value = "2"
        }
```

This results in:

```
Error: 
  Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
  Message: The OData request is not supported.
  Inner error:
```

Also is there a way to query all flagged messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flag` property is currently only available from the `/beta` endpoint. The [beta message object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/message) returns a `flag` property that holds a [followupFlag](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/followupflag) object.

```
"flag": {
    "flagStatus": "flagged",
    "dueDateTime": {
        "dateTime": "2017-08-29T04:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "startDateTime": {
        "dateTime": "2017-08-29T04:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

Please note that the beta endpoint isn't fully supported by the SDK. You can call into the beta endpoint but the classes are generated from the production prototypes so properties only in beta (such as `flag`) will not be populated.